# igraph read graph hang in OS X

Tags: r, macos, igraph, osx-yosemite

I use igraph r package. I have a ncol formatted graph file and uses

```
g <- read.graph('~/tmp/graph.ncol', format = 'ncol', weights="yes")
```

to read to memory. While this command and graph file runs fine for a few minutes under Ubuntu 14.04. Using the same machine with OS X 10.10 the command runs and never ends. I also tried another same graph in graphml format with same result.

This is a macbook pro that after upgrading to OS X 10.10, the refit/refind no longer works for me to boot into 14.04, so I decided to use OS X for a while and encountered this. The igraph package is installed by source in ubuntu while installed by binary from cran in OS X. I' ve also tried using the source package to compile igraph r package locally and got the same hanging result. Anyone experience similar things? Not sure if it is an OS X 10.10 thing.

Comment: This is very little information to go by. Can you produce some example (simulated) data that mimics this behavior?

Comment: I tried a few file sizes by truncating the ncol file. File sizes of 20M (1000000 lines) and below are fine. Now file with 10000000 lines is hanging. The whole file is 700M. Similar thing never occured in ubuntu on this machine and another machine with archlinux. The free memory should be enough.

Comment: Have you tried re-compiling the `igraph` library from scratch on Yosemite? I don't have a large graph file handy to test, but the compile worked fine after I downloaded the source package and did it from the command line vs RStudio (from within RStudio it couldn't find `gfortran-4.8` and there have been reports of path weirdness with RStudio & R after a Yosemite install).

Comment: I tried recompiling the igraph library and same result.

Comment: I think this is a bug, will investigate here: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/746

Comment: It seems that it is 10.10 specific, at least I don't see it on 10.9. A workaround is to read the file as a table, using `read.table()` or something similar, and then convert it to an igraph graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it only happens when the file path includes `~` like `~/tmp/graph.txt`, that it begins to use tempfile and calling `read.graph.toraw` that causes the trouble. I can avoid using that `~`. This is a workaround good enough for me.